# PHP explode() con espacios

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$pal = "botella, frasco, recipiente, bandeja, plato, barril";
$pal = explode(",",$pal);
```

Mi pregunta es, si habiendo un espacio luego de cada coma presente, ¿se puede dejar el explode tal como está o se debe colocar **", "** en vez de **","** ?

Comment: Eso dependerá de si necesitas que las palabras en el array queden sin espacio o no. Si las necesitas sin espacio, entonces puedes usar ", ", siempre y cuando tengas certeza de que habrá un sólo espacio. En caso de no tenerla,  podrías usar "," y aplicar la función trim con array_map para quitar los espacios a todos los elementos del array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependerá de como quieres que se almacenen los elementos en tu array.

Si lo que quieres es que te genere un array simplemente con los nombres de los elementos (sin espacios al inicio de cada elemento) deberías usar `", "`:

Con este código:

```
$pal = "botella, frasco, recipiente, bandeja, plato, barril";
$pal = explode(", ",$pal);
print_r($pal);
```

Obtendrías la siguiente salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => botella
    [1] => frasco
    [2] => recipiente
    [3] => bandeja
    [4] => plato
    [5] => barril
)
```

Si por el contrario quieres que se mantenga ese espacio al inicio de cada elemento entonces deberías usar `","`:

Con este código:

```
$pal = "botella, frasco, recipiente, bandeja, plato, barril";
$pal = explode(",",$pal);
print_r($pal);
```

Obtendrías la siguiente salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => botella
    [1] =>  frasco
    [2] =>  recipiente
    [3] =>  bandeja
    [4] =>  plato
    [5] =>  barril
)
```

Como puedes observar, en este segundo caso se mantiene el espacio al inicio de los elementos.

Comment: Con o sin indicar el espacio el resultado del Array() queda sin espacios. Probado en Firefox.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Realmente el navegador da lo mismo porque el php se ejecuta en el servidor. De todas maneras, mira la [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/caf96e7a31dbbb4a63b49c9189d4f034edf6de9e). La salida no es la misma.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz intenta imprimir el resultado de `explode()` dentro de una etiqueta `<pre>` y verás la diferencia... Además, queda más evidente cuando, en vez de usar `print_r` [se usa `var_dump()`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9eb2e8865a4e14229254ff6b0f51e11456273834)